# Proper placement of suffix while using the first name only

Tags: suffixes

Ordering a gravestone and want to make sure the suffix is used correctly.  While the last name is on the bottom to be shared by spouse,  I need to put Edward H. II up top.  The proper name is Edward H. Jones II.

Comment: If you want to keep the surname at the bottom, rather than simply repeating it, I would at least add a comma before the numeral: “Edward H., II”. And of course also make sure to choose a font and style for the numeral that clearly set it off as a numeral so no one ends up thinking his name was Edward H. Il Jones (that says “IL”, rather than “ii”).

Answer (score 1):

It does seem odd to have the numeric suffix without the surname.

One way around the problem is to move the surname: "Edward H Jones II and his wife Clarabel", which is a fairly standard headstone inscription.

[image: Gravestone]

[John Edward Cooper](http://johnedwardcooper.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/family-history-1900-onwards.html)

Or: repeat the surname, which is also common.

[image: Gravestone]

[English Rose Memorials](http://www.englishrosememorials.co.uk/services)

Answer (score -3):

Edward H. II and "namehere" Jones is correct.

Comment: Answers are expected to give more objective reasoning than just stating as fact, with nothing to support it, that something is or is not correct.