# Proper address for married couple when husband is a Jr

Tags: american-english, surnames

I have been unable to find a complete answer to my question in any source I have consulted.
I want to make a donation in memory of my deceased parents.  I would like to use both of their first names if possible, and my father was a Jr.  Should the proper format be: John and Mary Smith Jr. or Mr. John Smith Jr. and Mrs. Mary Smith? I believe the Jr. is restrictive and so I have omitted the comma.

Comment: Very similar to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133153/proper-placement-of-suffix-while-using-the-first-name-only

Comment: @AndrewLeach Similar, but enough difference in context and situation that I feel it deserves it's own question.  Now if the OP were asking about formatting a gravestone...

Comment: I am not sure if we ever used Jr. and Sr. in Britain, but if we did the practice certainly died out a long time ago.

Comment: A wife still often enough takes the husbands last name, but when stated alone (which is not what you're asking about) it is simply 'Jane Edwards' if her husband is 'John Edwards, Jr.'

Comment: I am reminded of the mock complaining letters to BBC from Monty Python..."signed, Brigadier Arthur Gormanstrop (Mrs.)...

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_%28name%29#Generational_titles) at least (I know, not the best source, but first I found in a quick google search):

> A wife who uses the title Mrs. would also use her husband's full name, including the suffix. In less formal situations, the suffix may be omitted. Hence: Mrs. Lon Chaney Jr. on a wedding invitation, but Mrs. L. Chaney or simply Shannon Chaney for a friendly note. Widows are entitled to retain their late husband's full names and suffixes, but divorcees may not continue to style themselves with a former husband's full name and suffix, even if they retain the surname.

Further, it is more correct to name the wife's name first, then the husbands. (see Crane's Blue Book of Social Stationery)

As such:  "Mary and John Smith Jr." (or alternatively: "Mary and John Smith, Jr.")

Note: With regards to whether to use a comma or not when using Jr., Sr., etc, see this [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Jr.Sr.III.html) page.